Is this electrical configuration realizable with a dual meter panel?
Desired end state - dual meter pedestal panel near a pole on our property.
Main house is currently underground 200 Amps derated to 175 for due to 12kW solar.  New ADU on a separate meter needs new 100Amps+/-, remodeled ag building needs new 60Amps+/-.
In the new 2 meter panel I would like to have 2 more circuits for additional solar and 2 more circuits for a tankless water heater at least.
SDGE (San Diego, CA) requires a separate meter for the ADU.  This could be a completely separate single meter on a pedestal but then I'd have two sets of conduit coming off the pole.  Not a huge deal but one dual meter is more desirable, I will do two separate panels if necessary.
So, to summarize, one meter serves house, ag building, tankless water heater and new solar.  Second meter serves ADU.
Really good discussion and a similar situation at this link: 400 amp meter base combo

Tankless water heater can require allocating as much as 120A and still not give you enough water. Don't do it!

Water heater only serves one shower, one vanity

@DIYBill -- is the tankless heater being put in because the bathroom is serving is too remote to get hot water in a reasonable timespan, or...?

Electric tankless is being added because we converted from propane water heaters to all electric in the main house.  And the sub panel that feeds that end of the house does not have enough Amps to handle the tankless comfortably.

No, you can't get what you want
As it turns out, there is no single box that will provide a 400A meter socket as part of a multisocket configuration that is acceptable to your utility.  This is because unitary multimeter hardware only goes up to 200/225A, and 400A test-block-bypass sockets (a la EUSERC, as your utility is an EUSERC member) aren't used for most commercial work, so they aren't available as modules for modular metering hardware, either.
But, you can get what you need
However, it is possible to construct a metering setup that fits your requirements, and provides room for additional expansion even, with the aid of some fabricobbling.  This does assume that you have enough space on a full 200A service to add the ~11kW tankless heater you're proposing, though. If that's not the case because your Article 220 load calculations show that your service is already full to the brim, you'll either need to use a 6 gallon point-of-use tank instead of the tankless or look for very low-flow fixtures in the 1-1.25GPM range that would let you shrink the tankless down to 5-7kW from the 11-13kW that would otherwise ordinarily be required for a full bathroom.  (You'd also need a 2-pole 30A branch breaker to replace the existing 60A solar breaker in your panel.)
You'll need:

A 400A, single-phase, EUSERC compliant termination (tap) box along with 3" and 3/4" "Myers" (NEMA 4X) hubs.  (One example is the Siemens WMMB1400; a Milbank PB-014-NK can also be used.  Just make sure that the box has enough solid area on the top of its right side to mount the 3/4" hub to!)
Three Penn-Union PB3-350S1 3-termination, single 3/8" bolt mount stacker (panelboard) lugs, along with a single 3/8" bolt of the same pitch as the termination box's load lug mounting bults, but 1/2" longer than them.  (If your termination box uses 1/2" load lug mounting bolts instead of 3/8", then a set of three IHI 3S250-53-81 lugs can be used instead.  The IHI lugs can also be used in conjunction with a trio of 3/8" ID by 1/2" OD by 3/8" long zinc plated spacers (McMaster-Carr #93441A457 or equivalent) if you can't get the Penn-Union lugs.)
An EUSERC-compliant, overhead-feed-capable, test-block-bypass equipped 400A meter main with either a single 400A disconnect or 2 200A disconnects in separate compartments, as well as a 3" bolt-on hub.  I would use a Siemens MK0603S1400SCS fitted with an EC56856 hub and a SUK350TA lug kit for the meter compartment as well as 2 QN2200H and a Q260H for this; it supplies 2 200A service disconnects in separate compartments as well as an additional 200A tap for renewable energy, which we can make good use of here.
An EUSERC-compliant, overhead-feed-capable, 100A meter main with a 3/4" hub fitted to the top.  This can be a Siemens MM0202L1125ESC, fitted with a Q2100H main breaker and a EC38594 top hub, or an equivalent part from another manufacturer.
A 200A, general duty, NEMA 3R, non-fused safety switch, to serve as the visible break disconnect required by SDG&E interconnect rules. (A Siemens GNF365R with its bonding screw pulled and a HG61234 grounding bar fitted will do the trick.)
A pair of 18" radius, 3" trade size rigid conduit sweep elbows, joined together with a 3" threaded conduit coupling, as well as a 3/4" rigid conduit sweep elbow.
Two 1.25" diameter by 3" long nipples with locknuts.
~75' of 250kcmil, ~5' of 1/0 AWG, and ~15' of 2AWG XHHW-2 aluminum wire.
A pair of Mersen MPDB67011 power distribution blocks.
Enough 4/4/4/4 quadplex to run from the house to the meter rack.
Enough 2/2/4/6 quadplex (Mobile Home Feeder) for runs from the metering rack to the barn (ag building) and ADU.
PVC conduit and adapter fittings.  This consists of either 1" schedule 80 to protect the stubups for the direct buried cables going off to the ADU, house solar disconnect, and barn, or 1" (for the solar) and 1.5" PVC conduit if you'd rather pull those runs through conduit instead.
Strut, pipe, and backboard, sufficient to fashion an 8' wide meter rack that can hold all of this up, as well as appropriate fasteners to attach the equipment to the meter rack and the various meter rack parts to each other.
A few feet of 1/0 bare copper wire to bond the termination box with.
About 15-20' of 6AWG bare copper wire for grounding, to go with a pair of 8' ground rods and matching ground rod clamps, as well as a pair of 1/2" "Kenny" clamps (Arlington GC50 or equivalent).
A 60A non-fused AC disconnect, along with a two-port, 14-4 range-taking, Al/Cu rated insulated mechanical ("Polaris") connector.
Enough 6/3 UF-B to get from the main panel to where the pullout disconnect can be fitted to transition from the house wiring to the stubup, as well as a trio of Ilsco MAC-618s to splice things in at the main panel, and a pair of NM/UF clamps suitable for a 6/3 cable.
A 12-space, 200A, NEMA 3R main lug loadcenter with a 60A, 2-pole breaker in it. (A Siemens SNW1225L1200 with a Q260 in it will do the job)
And a 200A main breaker for your existing panel.

The first step is to get the meter rack erected in the correct spot.  This will likely require an underground dip from the pole for your new 400A service, as EUSERC termination boxes are designed exclusively for wires coming in from underground.  You'll want this dip to be as far to the left of the rack as possible, by the way, with the existing conduit set so that it's close to the right edge of the rack.
From there, we then kit out the equipment.  The termination box gets its load lugs replaced with the lugs I specified, except for the neutral position, which gets its OEM lug removed then reinstalled atop the tongue of the new lug, as we'll need it to make the bonding connection, something that should be done at this point as well.  The two NEMA 4X hubs also get fitted to the termination box at this point, with the 3" one going on the far right of the box's hood and the 3/4" one going in the right side of the box below any cover plate that may be present there and as close to the back of the box as is practicable.
The 400A meter-main I specify gets 200A mains in the left (solar) and right disconnect compartments, with the 60A main in the middle disconnect compartment.  (If needed, you can swap the middle and right compartments, but the left compartment on the Siemens meter-main in question is reserved for solar duty.)  It also has a 1.25" knockout punched in the lower left side of the left-hand compartment, in line with the rear knockouts, as well as having the 1/2" knockout removed from the bottom left compartment and a Kenny clamp inserted into it, appropriate knockouts removed from the bottom of the middle and right compartments, and the hub fitted to the metering (utility) compartment in place of the corresponding blank plate.
We then move on to installing the 100A main breaker and 3/4" hub to the 100A meter main, twisting out the large knockout in the bottom right to the appropriate size, whether it be 1" or 1.5", and twisting out one of the 1/2" knockouts in said meter main for the other Kenny clamp.  Finally, we rig up the safety switch with its grounding bar, pulling the bonding screw out of it if is installed from the factory while we are in here.  We also take the opportunity at this point to pull the bond screw out of the solar combiner, since we don't need that either.
It's the big day
With the prep work basically done, we can now start installing the equipment on the rack.  First up is the termination (pull) box, as it needs to be connected to the conduit coming from the utility; you'll need to punch the appropriate knockout in the bottom yourself as part of this installation, as it's important that the pull box be as far left on the rack as possible to make room for all the things.  We then attach the conduit sweeps to the pullbox, with the accompanying disassembly and reassembly of the hubs.
From there, we install the two meter-mains.  The 400A main goes on the right so that its hub mates up with the conduit elbows, while the 100A main goes in the middle.  Installing the nipple in the left side of the 400A main comes next, followed by the safety switch, and the other nipple going out the back of the safety switch to the lower back of the AC combiner on the other side.
We can then run the various trenches and conduits or buried cables now that we know where they land (from left to right they are the main service, the ADU feeder, the solar feed from the house, the load feeder to the house, and the feeder to the ag building).  At the house end of the new solar feed, we fit the 60A pullout disconnect, running the UF cable out of it and off to the house's breaker box, then wiring its hots to the pullout's hots, the neutral to the Polaris connector, and the ground to the disconnect's grounding block.
We then pull any remaining underground wires through the conduits.  The 4/4/4/4 solar run lands on the remaining lugs on the pullout, with its neutral going into the remaining port on the Polaris connector.  At the other end, the circuit lands normally at the combiner panel, with the hots going to the breaker load lugs, the neutral to the neutral bar, and the ground to the grounding bar.
The safety switch then receives its line run, consisting of a pair of 250kcmil hots running from the two outside line lugs of the switch, through the nipple, and off to the two load lugs on the solar breaker in the meter-main, along with a 2AWG neutral wire that runs from the neutral lug in the solar compartment to the line neutral on the safety switch.  This is followed by its own load run, consisting of two more 250 kcmil hots running from the outer load lugs on the safety switch to the line lugs on the combiner panel and more 2AWG running from the load neutral on the safety switch to the line neutral lug on the combiner panel.
The other two new underground runs land conventionally in their respective compartments: hots to the service disconnect, neutral to the neutral lug (large lug), and ground to the ground lug (small lug).  Before we cut over the service, though, we do need to finish out the rack, and this consists of a few steps.  First, the conductor runs from the tap box to the meter mains need to be fitted, with 6 250kcmil wires (2 parallel sets of 3) going from the triple lugs we put on the tap box to the line lugs we fitted to the 400A meter-main via the 3" sweeps, and 2AWG wires going from the remaining triple lug openings on the tap box to the 100A meter-main's overhead lugs via the 3/4" sweep.
We then ground everything at the rack, starting at the 400A meter-main with our 6AWG grounding wire coming from the left-hand grounding lug and out of the "Kenny" clamp, then running it through the clamp for each grounding rod before sending it back up and off to the 100A meter-main's grounding lug via its "Kenny" clamp.  (The safety switch is grounded via the conduit nipple from the meter-main, and the termination box is bonded to neutral as one would for a meter-socket or other line-side device.)
Finally, we can cut the service from the house over to the new metering setup, landing its wires as one'd expect, and have the utility power up the new rack.
After-cutover cleanup
Now that the house is running on the new service equipment, we can clean up a few things.  The first step is cutting the solar over to the new coupling point; this is done by removing the neutral for it from the neutral bar and the hots from the breaker, then using the MAC-Blocks (or suitable wirenuts if you must) to splice the connections coming down from the solar inverter to the 6/3 UF that you ran from the "spa box" to the panel.  We can then replace that 175A main breaker with the 200A main to restore the full capacity of your panel, freeing up a bit of amperage for the tankless while you're at it.
Last, but not least, you finish this saga by installing the new water heater for the remotely-located bathroom, and doing the electrical work necessary at the barn (ag building) and ADU.  Do mind your Article 547 compliance on the ag building, by the way!
A bit of rationale and Code
Note that there are a few things in that setup that may seem...odd at first.  The extra solar disconnect is a utility requirement, called out on page 806.2 of SDGE's service standards.  It's not unique to SDGE, or even California, though.  Just about all US utilities require solar systems to supply a disconnect capable of visibly breaking the conductors, especially with the possibility in your case of going up to 48kW, well in excess of the 30kW threshold that triggers the visible-open requirement for SDGE.
Speaking of the solar, the neutral is mostly run with it for completeness' sake, which explains why we undersize it dramatically from the combiner box to the main solar disconnect.  (Were you to have a production meter, you'd have to land the neutral there by SDGE rules, even though a single phase production meter on a split-phase system has no use for it at all!)
Finally, we get to the issue of the ag building.  Buildings that are doing serious agricultural work often have dusty, wet, or corrosive environments in them, and animals really don't appreciate walking on a voltage gradient for that matter.  As a result, I would strongly recommend fitting the ag building out with a concrete-encased electrode in the perimeter footings paired with an equipotential mesh in the slab.  (This is similar to a swimming pool, save for the fact that we also need a good grounding electrode for the building as well.)
